# client-server chat program problem on serversocket

Tags: java, javafx, client-server

I am doing a client server chat project. where client A and client B shoud be connected to the server. i can connect Client A  with server but problem occoured in client B. 
I want to connect client A and Client B with server. Client A is connected succesfully.  and Also i want to communicate with Client A and Client B. But i failed if any one help me i will really appriciate. 
Thanks

```
    String msgin = "";
try{
    ss= new ServerSocket(5000);
    s= ss.accept();
    din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    while(!msgin.equals("exit")) {
        msgin = din.readUTF();
        msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Client A:\t"+msgin);
           }
}catch(IOException e){

}
String msgIn = "";
try{
    ss= new ServerSocket(6000);
    s= ss.accept();

    din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    while(!msgIn.equals("exit")) {
        msgIn = din.readUTF();
        msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Clint B:\t"+msgIn);
           }
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

client A

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyClientSocket().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
     try{
        s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String msgin="";
        while(!msgin.equals("exit")){
        msgin = din.readUTF();
        msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Server:\t"+msgin);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

}
```

Client B

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyClientServerB().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    try{
        s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",6000);

        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        String msgIn="";
        while(!msgIn.equals("exit")){
        msgIn = din.readUTF();
        msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Server:\t"+msgIn);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow more than one client to connect to the server at the same time, you will need to use multithreading. Try creating a new thread per client that connects. Servers are long-running programs, so it should continually listen for new client connections by looping.

Here's the logic you may consider trying:

```
try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
}

while (true) {

        Socket clientSocket;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             // handle each client independently 
        }
        t.start();

 }
```

Comment: Right now you have two servers, not one. If you want two clients connected to the same server at the same time, you need multithreading.